# How to make a dataview draggable with animations

Tags: javascript, html, extjs6

I found this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2d8p&view/editor) that answer in part to my question but further I need that the item dragged make the other items reorder dinamically. 
Any ideas?

I'm using Extjs 6.5.3 modern.

Comment: Look into [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) and specifically [RowReorder](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/) extension. It's mobile-friendly too.

Comment: I was looking for a sencha Extjs 6.5.3 solution @Alex but thanks

Comment: Okay. Just for reference for the future. :)

Comment: Reading Material for [`Ext.drag.Source`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/modern/Ext.drag.Source.html). "*A wrapper around a DOM element that allows it to be dragged.*"

Comment: Yeah, did you see [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2d8p&view/editor) ? It's pretty much what I want, I just want to go further.

Comment: Yeah, I checked it. I've never used `Extjs`, that's why I'm just supplying useful references.